# Write a query to display the job with the lowest average salary in the company

Tags: sql, postgresql

So basically the emp table has `emp(job,sal....)`
I have tried so many things including `min(avg(sal))` but combining two aggregate functions is not possible. 
trying something like `SELECT min(x.avg) FROM (SELECT AVG(sal)as avg FROM emp group by job)x;` it will only display the min(sal) but rather i want to display the job. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order by` and `limit`.  But critically, you need to select `job`!

```
SELECT job
FROM emp 
GROUP BY job
ORDER BY AVG(sal)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. i tried that but i am only required to return only job.

Comment: @HanisHapsa: Just drop `AVG(sal)` from the `SELECT` list. The query still works. If multiple jobs tie on their average, the "winner" is arbitrary. You need to define a tiebreaker ...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to select 1 column from Gordon's answer -

```
SELECT job
FROM (SELECT job, AVG(sal)
      FROM emp 
      GROUP BY job
      ORDER BY AVG(sal)
      LIMIT 1) T;
```